# Stop AJAX job on another ajax call jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-templates

I'm trying to make some ajax tabs with continuoisly refreshing content.
The application is working on django 1.11 so, every ajax call have CSRF script (you can skip it if you are not familiar)

**Step 1:**

Call tabs content via AJAX

```
$('#{{ chat_friend.profile_company_user_uuid }}').click(function () {

    $.ajax({

        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {

            function getCookie(name) {

                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }

            if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
            }
        },

        type: "POST",
        url: "/chat/view/",
        data: {
            id: "{{ chat_friend.profile_company_user_uuid }}", // < note use of 'this' here
            access_token: $("#access_token").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#chat-message').html(data);
        }
    });

})
;
```

DONE!

**Step 2:**

Call AJAX REFRESH with intervals

```
setInterval(function () {

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }

            if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
            }
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/chat/refresh/",
        data: {
            id: "{{ opponent.profile_company_user_uuid }}", // < note use of 'this' here
            access_token: $("#access_token").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#inner-chat').html(data);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

DONE

BUT, when I call AJAX of another tab, then refreshing code is not removed, however It becomes 2 (or more, depends how many times you switch the tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attached code I can't find the reason why it happens, but this must be because of your `setInterval` function is called again for each tab click. What you can try is to clear that interval once for each tab click. Modify your code like this:

```
var timer = setInterval(/*your refresh-ajax here*/);
```

And inside your tab-click-ajax clear that interval.

```
success: function (data) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  $('#chat-message').html(data);
}
```

Please, let me know if this doesn't help.

**Edit**

Assuming that refresh-script is inside tab-ajax response, which is straightly attached to html, I think this causes the problem. Every time you add new `<script>` it is executed. That's why you have multiple fires of your refresh function. I've imitated this behavior in a very simple way and one possible solution is to modify my previous code:

```
timer = setInterval(/*your refresh-ajax here*/); //without var
```

Try to declare `var timer;` as global variable inside `<script>`, that is always present on the page. This helps in my simple imitation.

Another way is to move `clearInterval(timer);` from `success:` to new script just before `setInterval` but this makes no difference. Anyway, timer needs to be global.

Comment: I'm sorry Alex, but it didn'y work. May be because refresh ajax is placed in tab ajax response...?

Comment: You mean the `<script>` with refresh function is inside tab ajax response? If so, than it explains the problem. Every time you modify html, newly added script is executed. It creates one more interval. Let me think a little.

Comment: Yes, absolutely so... And, as it's dynamic tabs, every tab has it's own ajax script, which recieves response according to the tab id in ajax post body... any sugestions?

Comment: I think we should make some changes to the script, because, now tab change realy stops interval refresh, but it stops it before it starts to refresh, so refresh script is not working now...

Comment: Alex, we did it! Your answer is correct, but to prevent refresh stop before it starts we need to add TimeOut for refresh script, can you edit your answer. Thank you!